# Change href of <a> element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please, code to change domain in href (html, JavaScript).

Exemple:

```
<a id="NewL" href="http://exemple.com/indice.html">Indice</a>
```

To:

```
<a id="NewL" href="http://exemple.net/indice.html">Indice</a>
```

Exemple code not working:

```
<script  type = "text/javascript" >
function replace() {
    var aEls = document.getElementById('NewL').getElementsByTagName('a');
    aEls.href = aEls.href.replace('http://exemple\.com', 'http://exemple\.net');
}
</script>
```

Thanks, @t.niese:

```
<a id="NewL" href="http://exemple.com/indice.html">Indice</a>

<script  type="text/javascript" >
function replace() {
    var aEl = document.getElementById('NewL');
    aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('http://exemple.com', 'http://exemple.net');
}
replace();
</script>
```

Please help me, not change in various ID in same page:

```
   <a id="NewL" href="http://exemple.com/indice.html">Indice</a>
   <a id="NewL" href="http://exemple.com/indice2.html">Indice 2</a>

    <script  type="text/javascript" >
    function replace() {
        var aEl = document.getElementById('NewL');
        aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('http://exemple.com', 'http://exemple.net');
    }
    replace();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName):

> [...]The subtree underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element itself.[...]

so you search for the elements with the tag name `a` within your element with the id `NewL`

Because `document.getElementById('NewL')` is already your `a` element, you won't need the `getElementsByTagName('a')`, as of that you should only write:

```
 var aEl = document.getElementById('NewL');
```

Also your `replace` is wrong, you don't need to escape the `.` if you pass the search as string.

```
 aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('htp://exemple.com', 'htp://exemple.net');
```

Beside that `Element.getElementsByTagName()` returns a list of elements, so even if your search would have been correct, you would need to use a loop to iterate through that result.

Comment: @jmsmarcelo Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aakauntq/) and it is working fine, the `.com` is replaced by the `.net`, so you most likely did something else wrong.

Comment: @jmsmarcelo Are there error messages in the console? Are you calling the replace method?

Comment: @t.niese, Please, And when have several tag it only works in the first.

Comment: @jmsmarcelo ids have to be unique so you can only have on element with `id="NewL"` on your page, without knowing how you can identify the links you want to change it is not possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript to the following:

```
<script  type = "text/javascript" >
function replace() {
    var aEl = document.getElementById('NewL');
    aEl.href = aEl.href.replace('htp://exemple\.com', 'htp://exemple\.net');
}
</script>
```

You already selected the element by the `getElementById` no need to find the a class in it. Also you mispelled the variable which I changed to `aEl`